# ExecuteReader for executing Insert/Update query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, executereader

Ok so I was just given this old vb.net(2008) program to make some changes to and I found something weird. The Insert/Update queries are being executed with `ExecuteReader`, it goes something like this

```
Dim sqlcommand as new SqlCommand("Insert query", connection)
Dim sqldatareader as SqlDataReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader()
```

And for some reason it works, it inserts/updates the data properly. Is there any draw backs to this? should I bother going through the program and change everything to `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: I don't know about performance, but if you want to get the number of records modified you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` which will return the number of records affected by your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute Reader is normally used when you expect your SQL Command to return some output. Such as Select a row. But if you don't have any results, but just a plain Insert or Update, then ExecuteNonQuery is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the `INSERT` command, if it has an OUTPUT clause then it can actually return data.